# How to display text in a box based on serial port existing data

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, serial-port, serial-communication

I have a serial com GUI and I need to have text displayed in a box *based* on what the serial port's existing data is, but not *exactly* what the serial port data is. For example, if the serial port's existing line is "!+0007.", I would like my textbox to read "Type K". I've tried multiple methods such as If-Then and Select Case and am not having any luck.

```
    Private Sub GetInput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetInput.Click
    SerialPort1.Write("$" & ComboBox4.Text & ComboBox5.Text & "06" & vbCr)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    If SerialPort1.ReadExisting = "!+0007." Then
        GetInputBox.Text = "Type K"
    End If

    SerialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer()
End Sub
```

No luck with that

```
    Private Sub GetInput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetInput.Click
    Dim value As String = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
    SerialPort1.Write("$" & ComboBox4.Text & ComboBox5.Text & "06" & vbCr)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    Select Case value
        Case value = "!+0007."
            GetInputBox.Text = "Type K"
    End Select
    SerialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer()
End Sub
```

None here either.
Any suggestions?

Comment: In your first example, try `SerialPort1.ReadLine()` instead of `SerialPort1.ReadExisting`.  You could also experiment with increasing the value in `Sleep`.

Comment: @JimHewitt ReadLine() causes the program to freeze

Comment: Did you try setting `SerialPort1.NewLine = vbCR`?

Comment: @JimHewitt yep, still freezes

Comment: What do you get if you do this: `SerialPort1.Write("$" & ComboBox4.Text & ComboBox5.Text & "06" & vbCr)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50) 
        GetInputBox.Text = SerialPort1.ReadExisting`

Comment: I get the string that the serial port is sending back. But I don't need the string to display exactly as it is, I need it to display something else based on what it is. Could I use an if statement with `SerialPort1.ReadExisting.contains("!+0007.")`?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Start by logging the data that you send and received using `Console.Writeline`
2. It looks like your call ReadExisting before sending data to the serial port, then you wait, then you test it. What I suspect you're needing to do (and you should clarify this) is to send data to the com port, wait, then read the response. In which case you want:

   ```
        SerialPort1.Write("$" & ComboBox4.Text & ComboBox5.Text & "06" & vbCr)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        Dim value As String = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
   ```
3. You're clearing your outgoing buffer but not your incoming buffer so most likely you'll have partial packets from previous comms in there.
4. Don't assume you'll always get 1 packet from 1 reponse ... hence the need to log the data.

Comment: So I've added the code you've said and put after it `If value = "!+0007." Then getinputbox.text = "Type K"`

Comment: Ok ... do you have a question? Or some logs for me to look at?

Comment: I didn't have any luck with what your suggestion, I just end up with a blank text box. I'm very new to this, so I'm open to anything